# What is a Shim?

Tags: terminology, definition, vocabulary, shim

What's the definition of a Shim?

Comment: See also question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512690/what-is-the-difference-between-the-shim-and-facade-adapter-patterns

Answer (score 205):

## Simple Explanation via Cartoon

[image: My Dog Ralph is one lucky bash-tard (double pun intended)]

#### Summary

A shim is some code that takes care of what's asked (by 'interception'), without anyone being any wiser about it.

#### Example of a Shim

An example of a shim would be rbenv (a [`ruby`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) tool). Calls to  ruby commands are "shimmed". i.e. when you run `bundle install`, rbenv intercepts that message, and reroutes it according to the specific version of Ruby you are running. If that doesn't make sense [try this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118374/4880924), or just think of the fairy god mother intercepting messages and delivering apposite outcomes.

That's it!

#### Important Clarifications on this example

- Note: Like most analogies, this is not perfect: usually Ralph will get EXACTLY what he asked for - but the mechanics of HOW it was obtained is something Ralph doesn't care about. If Ralph asks for dog food, a good shim will deliver dog food.
- I wanted to avoid semantic arguments etc. Here's my thinking: talking about adapter,  facade, proxy, gang of four patterns - too much conceptual complexity. Introducing code? Pedagogically risky without a conceptual foundation. Encyclopedia / dictionary explanation? Boring, complex, time consuming to read - usually without a use-case. So I simplified it to a cartoon: hoping you can quickly / easily understand in a "fun" way and move on - if you prefer an academic definition, consider the [Wikipedia entry on shims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing))  <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Coz I get complaints about the analogies. I'm like...   ¯¯\*(ツ)*/¯¯  it takes time to create the concept, find the photos, photo-shop this stuff, to make it 'fun', and it was never intended to be a picture perfect scientific / academic definition.

Comment: I appreciated the simplified example - thank you (and Ralph) for that! Hope the steak was good.

Comment: One might be served by looking up the general definition of ‘shim’ first, it doesn’t need to be complicated.

Answer (score 97):

The term "shim" as defined in Wikipedia would technically be classified, based on its definition, as a "Structural" design pattern.  The many types of “Structural” design patterns are quite clearly described in the (some would say defacto) object oriented software design patterns reference ["Design Patterns, Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) better known as the ["Gang of Four"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

The ["Gang of Four"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) text outlines at least 3 well established patterns known as, "Proxy", "Adapter" and "Facade" which all provide “shim” type functionality.  In most fields it’s often times the use and or miss use of different acronyms for the same root concept that causes people confusion.  Using the word “shim” to describe the more specific “Structural” design patterns ["Proxy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Proxy_pattern), ["Adapter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and ["Facade"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) certainly is a clear example of this type of situation.  A "shim" is simply a more general term for the more specific types of "Structural" patterns "Proxy", "Adapter", "Facade" and possibly others.

Comment: This answer indicates that a shim is a design pattern (one of many), names some similar design patterns, and goes off on a tangent about how people get confused by different acronyms.  But it doesn't actually answer the original question of what a shim is, what it does, or how one is used.

Answer (score 33):

According to Microsoft's article ["Demystifying Shims"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170709125601/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2011/06/17/demystifying-shims-or-using-the-app-compat-toolkit-to-make-your-old-stuff-work-with-your-new-stuff/):

> It’s a metaphor based on the English language word shim, which is an
> engineering term used to describe a piece of wood or metal that is
> inserted between two objects to make them fit together better. In
> computer programming, a shim is a small library which transparently
> intercepts an API, changes the parameters passed, handles the
> operation itself, or redirects the operation elsewhere. Shims can also
> be used for running programs on different software platforms than they
> were developed for.

So a shim is a generic term for any library of code that acts as a middleman and partially or completely changes the behavior or operation of a program.  Like a true middleman, it can affect the data passed to that program, or affect the data returned from that program.

The Windows API is an example:

> The application is generally unaware that the request is going to a
> shim DLL instead of to Windows itself, and Windows is unaware that the
> request is coming from a source other than the application (because
> the shim DLL is just another DLL inside the application’s process).

So the two programs that make the "bread" of the "shim sandwich" should not be able to differentiate between talking to their counterpart program and talking to the shim.

**What are some pros and cons of using shims?**

Again, from the article:

> You can fix applications without access to the source code, or without
> changing them at all. You incur a minimal amount of additional
> management overhead... and you can fix a
> reasonable number of applications this way. The downside is support as
> most vendors don’t support shimmed applications. You can’t fix every
> application using shims. Most people typically consider shims for
> applications where the vendor is out of business, the software isn’t
> strategic enough to necessitate support, or they just want to buy some
> time.

Answer (score 17):

As for origins of the word, quoth Apple's Dictionary widget

```
noun
   a washer or thin strip of material used to align parts, 
   make them fit, or reduce wear.

verb ( shimmed, shimming) [ trans. ]
   wedge (something) or fill up (a space) with a shim.

ORIGIN early 18th cent.: of unknown origin
```

This seems to fit quite well with how web designers use the term.

Answer (score 13):

Shims are used in .net 4.5  Microsoft Fakes framework      [to isolate your application from other assemblies for unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx). Shims divert calls to specific methods to code that you write as part of your test

Answer (score 4):

As we could see in many responses here, a shim is a sort of adapter that provides functionality at API level which was not necessarily part of that API. This thread has a lot of good and complete responses, so I'm not expanding the definition further.

However, I think I can add a good example, which is the Javascript ES5 Shim (https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim):

Javascript has evolved a lot during the last few years, and among many other changes to the language specification, a lot of new methods have been added to its core objects.

For example, in the ES2015 specification (aka ES5), the method `find` has been added to the `Array` prototype. So let's say you are running your code using a JavasScript engine prior to this specification (ex: Node 0.12) which doesn't offer that method yet. By loading the ES5 shim, these new methods will be added to the `Array` prototype, allowing you to make use of them even if you are not running on a newer JavaScript specification.

You might ask: why would someone do that instead of upgrading the environment to a newer version (let's say Node 8)?

There is a lot of real cases scenarios where that approach makes sense. One good example:

Let's say you have a legacy system that is running in an old environment, and you need to use such new methods to implement/fix a functionality. The upgrade of your environment still a work in progress because there are compatibility issues that require a lot of code changes and tests (a critical component).

In this example, you could try to craft your own version of such functionality, but that would make your code harder to read, more complex, can introduce new bugs and will require tons of additional tests just to cover a functionality that you know it will be available in the next release.

Instead, you can use this shim and make use of these new methods, taking advantage of the fact that this fix/functionality will be compatible after the upgrade, because you are already using the methods known to be available in the next specification. And there is a bonus reason: since these methods are native to the next language specification, there is a good chance that they will run faster than any implementation that you could have done if you tried to make your own version.

Another real scenario where such approach is welcome is at browser level. Let's say you need to support old browser and want to take advantage of these newer features. Javascript is a language that allows you to add/modify methods in its core objects (like adding methods to Array prototype), and those shim libraries are smart enough to add such methods only if the current implementation is lacking of them.

PS:
1) You will see the term "Polyfill" related to these Javascript shims. Polyfill is a more specialized type of shim that is used to provide forward compatibility in different browser level specifications. By the way, my example above refers exactly to such example.

2) Shims are not limited to this example (adding functionality that will be available in a future release). There are different use cases that would be considered to be a shim as well.

3) If you are curious about how this specific polyfill is implemented, you can open Javascript [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) specs and scroll to the end of the page where you will find a canonical implementation for this method.

Answer (score 0):

**Current setup:**

Jan

```
client app(v1) -> server A (returns a response itself)
```

**Now you have a fancier server named B. You want to get rid of server A. What do you?**

August

```
client app(v2) -> server B (returns response)
client app(v1) -> server A (returns response)
```

Can you turn down server A?

You can't! Because older builds of your mobile application are still in use. What should you do then?

December (turn server A into a shim)

```
client app (v1) -> server A - > server B -> server A 
client app (v2) - > server B
```

You make the change at the servers. Basically server A no longer acts as like a real server. It's a fake front. You have to keep it around because you can't magically update the URL an old installed app on someone's phone who hasn't updated their app.

**This fake front is what's known as a shim.**

**What advantage does the shim offer?**

- The platform team and client teams can deprecate a server on their own separate schedules.
- You can stop development on the older server. Because all it does is relay things to the new server.

**Can you turn off server A?**
No. Because it’s still called by old apps. You can only turn it off if you forced your users to a newer app version.

Answer (score -2):

SHIM is another level of security check which is done for all the services, to protect upstream systems. SHIM Server validates every incoming request, with Headers User credentials, against the user credentials, which are passed in the request(SOAP / RESTFUL).