# pyenv - how to get more info re: "system", including version

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm on MacOS, and I have latest python installed via brew. A few months ago, I started using `pyenv` to be able to switch between latest python and a project that was fixed at python v3.8. I think I got it all set up but I'm confused. `pyenv` refuses to show me information about `system`:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version)
  3.8.6

$ pyenv version system
system (set by /Users/<user>/.pyenv/version)

$ cat ~/.pyenv/version
system
```

How do I get pyenv to show me the version and/or location of `system`?? Obviously, I can get info about system python when it's the one in use, but why doesn't `pyenv` show anything about it? Showing info about the current config seems like basic functionality for a config management tool.

By comparison, when I run `apt list --installed`, it shows me what's installed, whether installed by me or bundled with the OS. It doesn't just show a placeholder for things installed by the system.

So I'm frustrated that `pyenv` is doing this.

**Edit:** Wow, `nvm` is the same way. How? Why? Why do these tools have a built-in disregard for the system config?

Comment: `pyenv activate system ; python --version` ? The system version is not managed by pyenv, that's why it's the system version.

Comment: @Mephy Oh, so it's like Homebrew? Where the tool is a layer on top of the system, and so inherently there's a piece that the tool doesn't manage and might not even have access to.

Answer (score 1):

pyenv notifies you that you have a system version when you do:
`pyenv versions`

If you then do:
`pyenv global system`

> this does not actually set you to that as it would other versions:

like `pyenv global 3.11`

the correct way to determine your "system" version is:

```
/usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.9.6
```

Presumably you're using Python3, and this works for Mac OSX and python installed with brew, it may not work for your system.

For other systems it might work to do:

```
$ python --version
$ python3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyenv is a [shim tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116142/what-is-a-shim). It's used to intercept calls to `python` and `pip` and transparently give the correct binaries for these commands. When you call `python -m some_module`, pyenv will find the correct `python` binary that makes sense for that call, either because it's locally set by a `.python-version` file or set by the current shell using `pyenv shell` or `pyenv activate` commands.

Pyenv tries to not mess up with current python installations, because the environment system may use these tools, and should keep using whatever version they are already using. Thus, it simply packs the currently existing binaries as "system" and does not touch it, so that the existing system prior to installing pyenv keeps working as it was before.

As a best practice, I recommend you to create a new environment and set it with `pyenv global` to something different of system (e.g. `pyenv install 3.9.10 && pyenv virtualenv 3.9.10 myglobal && pyenv global myglobal`) -- so that your default application python is different from the operating system python, and thus you can't mess with the system; just leave system as is. If you want to check what system is, you can activate it and call it normally, `pyenv activate system ; python --version` will show the version, but it's not something you should be doing in the first place, so pyenv doesn't support it.

Comment: 1. Pyenv activate does not seem to be a command.
$ pyenv --version
pyenv 2.3.23
$ pyenv global system
also DOES NOT WORK:

$ python --version
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.7.11
  3.9.10

Comment: @Zargold the activate command surely exists. And `pyenv global system` works as long as pyenv created a system shim from a previously existing system-wide python installation. It looks like you may have a faulty or incomplete pyenv installation. Feel free to open a new question describing your issue in detail.

Comment: $ pyenv activate system                           .....                  ..... 
pyenv: no such command `activate'
...

Comment: pyenv help
--version   Display \
   commands    List all available \
   exec        Run \
   global      Set \
   help        Display \
   hooks       List \
   init        Configure \
   install     Install \
   latest      Print \
   local       Set \
   prefix      Display \
   rehash      Rehash \ 
   root        Display \
   shell       Set \
   shims       List \ 
   uninstall   Uninstall \
   version     Show \
   version-file   Detect \
   version-name   Show \ 
   version-origin   Explain \
   versions    List all
\  whence      List 
\  which       Display